# Perl: Add column from one file to the end of a second file

Tags: perl, substitution

I would like to add a specific column from File1 (A,B,C,D) next to the last column of File2 (a,b,c,d). An example input and output is shown below:

```
Input File1:
1   A
2   B
3   C 
4   D

Input File2:
11   a  
12   b  
13   c  
14   d  

Output:
11  a  A
12  b  B
13  c  C
14  d  D
```

This is my code, I'm having trouble specifying the substitution regex. Maybe there is a better way to do this all together?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $text = 'file1.txt';
my $column = 'file2.txt';

open IN, '<', $column or die "Can't open '$column' $!";
open TEXT, '<', $text or die "Can't open '$text' $!";
open OUT, '>>', 'output.txt' or die "Can't open 'output.txt' $!";

my @ref = <IN>;

while ( my $line = <TEXT> ) {
   $line =~ s/\s+$/$ref[1]/s;
   print OUT $line;
 }
```

UPDATE: Couldn't resolve with perl. Used awk instead:

```
awk -v f2=file2.txt ' { c = $2; getline < f2; print $0, c; } ' file1.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 


my @small   = qw/a b c d e/;
my @big = qw/A B C D E/;

my %hash;
@hash{@small} = @big;

print "$_ $hash{$_}\n" foreach sort keys %hash;
```

Comment: thank you for your script. The input files are actually quite large and so I read them into the arrays small and big, and ran the script as posted, however the output is not in 3 columns. The inserted column is being placed under data with a matching numeric value.

Comment: I realize that my question may have been poorly worded, I have edited the example input files to make it more clear

Comment: @EA00 if you're reading the file into arrays, are you making sure to `chomp` your input? The newlines in the file are probably what's causing your weird output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code, `@ref = <IN>` is going to put each line of the file as an element of the `@ref` array. Then on every iteration of your loop you try to insert `$ref[2]` which is the second line of the file. That's obviously not what you want.

You also have missed splitting up the lines of  by columns. Finally, remember array indices start at zero so if you want the second column, you're looking for element 1.

Remove the `@ref = <IN>` and read it one line at a time.

```
while (my $line = <TEXT>) {
   my $line2 = <IN>;
   my @line2_columns = split /\s/, $line2;
   $line =~ s/\s+$/$line2_columns[1]/s;
   print OUT $line;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the corrections. I have edited the script accordingly and am getting the following error: Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at ./script.pl line 16, <IN> line 5.

Comment: That means $line2_columns[1] is blank. Does your file have multiple spaces between each column? If so try `split /\s+/, $line2;` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the error, however the output is not in columns: 11 aA12 bB13 cC14 dD. Should I implement a push function?

Comment: @EA00 Probably your substitution is replacing the whitespace which includes the newline. Maybe change last line of while loop to put the newline back in, e.g. `print OUT $line . "\n";`